# Enable Read Only mode in Office Online Server for SharePoint Server 2016

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online

I have successfully integrated Office Online Server for SharePoint Server 2016 and successfully open documents in office online but there is option to edit in browser or open in word option which makes users having edit permission can edit the document.

But my requirement is to give them only **read option** to those document not edit. So that they can only read in browser. And my question is how to remove **edit in browser** or **open in word** option??

Answer (score 0):

Use [New-SPWOPISuppressionSetting](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219443.aspx). For example:

```
New-SPWOPISuppressionSetting -Extension "XLSX" -Action "edit"
```

Comment: Its not working in my Office Online Server of SharePoint Server 2016. I think its only applied to Office Web Apps which runs in SharePoint 2013.

Comment: This cmdlet is used for both OOS and WAC.

Comment: But its not working. I hit the mention code but edit option still there i can easily edit the document.

Comment: Did you specify the correct extension? I only gave an example.

Comment: I did Following: 
New-SPWOPISuppressionSetting -Extension DOCX -Action edit
New-SPWOPISuppressionSetting -Extension ODT -Action edit
New-SPWOPISuppressionSetting -Extension DOCM -Action edit